# Python quiz, using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

q = 0
s = -1
count = 0
correct = 0
incorrect = 0

question = ["Is this a quiz","Are you sure","Dont be","see its not a quiz"]

answer = ["yes","yes","ok","ok"]
answer_cap = ["Yes","Yes","Ok","Ok"]

root = Tk()

name = tk.Label(root,text = "GUI Quiz")
name.pack()

label = tk.Label(root,text = question[0])
label.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()



def out():
    global q,correct,incorrect,s,count
    count = count + 1
    ans = entry.get()
    print (ans)
    print (question[q])
    print (answer[q])
    if count < 4:
          if answer[q] or answer_cap[q] == ans :
              q = q + 1
              entry.delete(0, END)
              correct = correct + 1
              label.config(text = question[q])
          else:
              q = q + 1
              entry.delete(0, END)
              incorrect = incorrect + 1
              label.config(text = question[q])
    else:
        entry.delete(0, END)
        label.config(text = "Correct: "+str(correct) + " Incorrect:   "+str(incorrect))


def stop():
    global q,correct,incorrect
    q = 0
    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0
    entry.delete(0, END)
    label.config(text = question[0])

button = tk.Button(root,text = "Submit",command = out)
button.pack()

button_two = tk.Button(root,text = "Restart",command = stop)
button_two.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

nothing actually wrong with the code its just how I'm doing it. When I run module it will ask my four questions and I will give the answer, but no matter what I put it will say I got 3 correct and none wrong. Am I missing something obvious or is it how I layed out the code.

Comment: This statement will always be True "if answer[q] or answer_cap[q] == ans :" because answer[q] is not empty so if answer[q] will always be True.  Convert the answer to lower() so you only have to test for one case condition.  Also q+1, entry.delete and label.config don't belong under the inner if/else because you do that no matter what happens.

Comment: Thanks you've really helped, but I don't really understand when your talking about answer[q] is not empty?

Comment: "but no matter what I put it will say I got 3 correct" -- after the 4th question is asked, count == 4 so the if count < 4 statement does not execute, so +1 at the end of the function (and it should be if count < len(answer) so you can add and subtract questions easily).  Don't "q" and "count" do the same thing?

Comment: "q" and "count" do do the same, I just messed around with it trying to fix the code also I didn't know about "len(answer)" so thanks that new for me, you really help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your out function should not have 'count = count + 1' because this adds one to you score regardless of weather you were right or wrong; relocate the commented code.

```
def out():
    global q,correct,incorrect,s,count
    #count = count + 1
    ans = entry.get()
    print (ans)
    print (question[q])
    print (answer[q])
```